# Catching exception throwing by tasks

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

```
TaskScheduler ts= TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
try
{
    Task<T> task1 = ...
    task1.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        ...
        Task<T> task2 = ...
        task2.ContinueWith(u =>
        {
            ...
            Task<T> task3 = ...
            task3.ContinueWith(w =>
            {
                ...
            }, new CancellationToken(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, ts);
        }, new CancellationToken(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, ts);
    }, new CancellationToken(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, ts);
} 
catch(Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("...");
}
```

Hi. I have some code (as above). This doesn't work for me. I have three tasks which are working server-side but modifying UI, so all of them should result make in UI thread. What is more: 3rd task cannot run if 2nd complete with failure, and 2nd cannot run unless 1st is successfully completed. So if 1st one ends with a failure my tasks tree should throw exception and break rest of operations. How to achieve that in the simplest way?

**UPDATE**

now my code looks like

```
private async void SomeMethod()
{
 ...
 try
 {
      var r1 = await Method1(...);
      var r2 = await Method2(...);
  var r3 = await Method3(...);
 }
 catch
 {
      MessageBox.Show("..."); 
 }
}

private Task<...> Method1(...)
{
  Task<...> task = Task<...>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
         ...
         try
         {
               // Result is null (but that's ok) so 'index out of range exception' is thrown
               // It calls my method MyException with this exception (but I don't know in 
               // which thread and how to catch this (shouldn't be catch by async SomeMethod?)
               result = ....Results[0];
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
               MyException(ex);
         }
    return result;
    });
    return task;
}

public void MyException(Exception ex)
{
  throw ex;
}
```

But I still cannot catch exception.

**EDIT**
Solved. I don't catch exceptions (just ignore in Method1) and:

```
var r1 = await Method1(...);
if(r1!=null)
{
    var r2 = await Method2(...);
    var r3 = await Method3(...);
}
else
{
    ...do sth instead of catching ex
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest option is to use `await` here, as it will provide the error handling semantics you want with very little effort; allowing you to write code as if it were regular synchronous code:

```
try
{
    var firstResult = await SomethingAsync();
    var secondResult = await SomethingElseAsync(firstResult);
    var finalResult = await AnotherThingAsync(secondResult);
}
catch
{
    //handle an exception thrown by any of the above async operations.
}
```

If you can't do that (due to being on .NET 4.0), then you can use the `Then` method described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/11/21/10094564.aspx) to also get the semantics you want:

```
var finalTask = SomethingAsync()
.Then(firstResult => SomethingElseAsync(firstResult))
.Then(secondResult => AnotherThingAsync(secondResult));

finalTask.ContinueWith(t => HandleError(t.Exception),
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

`Then` is essentially a call to `ContinueWith`, but with different error handling semantics.  If the tasks being continued threw an exception then `Then` just propagates that exception, rather than running the continuation.  `ContinueWith` just runs the continuation and swallows the exception.

Comment: I find your solution appeals to me, but I cannot handle exception. I'm on .NET 4.5, so I tried to use
         try
        {
            ...
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(...);    
        }
but this doesn't catch exception from another thread. Any remarks?

Comment: @user2248836 Using `Wait` is not asynchronously, as both of the solutions I provided are.  However, if that isn't handling the error then it means that the task isn't being marked as faulted.  Either the error is entirely unrelated, or the task is itself creating new tasks that are erroring but it is not marking itself as faulted as a result.  If that's the case, the solution is to fix that so you're not in that position to begin with.

Comment: I actually did like you said, this `wait` was from another stackoverflow's post.
My solution breaks down in `SomethingAsync();` so Exception appears, but is invisible to my `catch`. So how could I fix that?

Comment: @user2248836 Is the `Task` marked as faulted and is it's `Exception` property set to the given exception?  If so, then the `catch` block will be run, assuming the exception is of a type that that `catch` block supports.  If not, as I said, you need to fix `SomethingAsync` so that it *does* do that.

Comment: oh right, my task isn't marked as faulted, because it's never finished. 
`SomeMethod()
{
     Task... = => ..
     {
         ....
         .... <- this line throws a exception (before returning result)
         return result;
     }
}`

I put this line into try catch block and call method MyException that throws Exception (I hope in UI thread?). How to catch this ex?